# SetTokenInformation and privileges

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to add a privilege to my process token (my process is running with admin rights).
I Can't use the AdjustTokenPrivileges because the process token does not contain my missing privilege. So, I tried to add the privilege to the token by SetTokenInformation. I'm pretty sure that I build the TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure in the right way and I get an INVALID_PARAMETER_ERROR when I called SetTokenInformation. So, I'm thinking that there is a problem with using this function on an existing tokens. In addition I found this remark in the function MSDN page: "Token-type information can be set only when an access token is created."

So, What else can I do?

Note: I'm doing it because my call to CreateProcessAsUser failed becuase I don't have SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilage.

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: [Here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/tip-run-process-in-system-account-scexe_topic16714_page4.html) is an interesting page on getting `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME`.

Comment: Which Windows version (UAC involved? Sure that you have admin token?)? Did you give https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315276 a try?

Answer (score 1):

You [can change a privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717797(v=vs.85).aspx) in a token but you can't add one. Keith Brown has a good section on the subject in his [outstanding book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604426) on windows security. In it he says that once the LSA finishes constructing the token "You cannot later inject additional privileges...".  I wish I could find a book like his that covers current windows security. Sigh.

Comment: I thought you can duplicate an existing token and modify it to your need as long as the token is not already attached to a process.